# Vim statusline filename without [Rails] appended to it

Tags: vim

I'm creating a custom statusline in vim with the following so far:

```
set statusline=%t
set laststatus=2
```

It's VERY simple but the problem is the filename shows up like so:

```
my_file.rb[Rails]
```

Is there a way to get it to show without "[Rails]"? I want just this

```
my_file.rb
```

Comment: Hello, what version of vim are you using?

Comment: I'm using MacVim. I thought I figured out a way to do it but it's not working. I'm not sure what's causing the [Rails] part to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Rails]` bit is probably coming from the [vim-rails plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567). The plugin will set a modified, local value for `statusline` when editing a Rails file (`:set statusline?` after seeing `[Rails]` in your status line to see that it has added `%{rails#statusline()}` to the end of the `statusline` value you set in your `.vimrc`). You can disable its `statusline` modifications by putting something like the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:rails_statusline = 0
```

Incidentally, the `[Rails]` bit does not represent the value of the `filetype` option (which you can get with the `%y` statusline item, if you want it). It is mostly just a static string (there is some code to make it look like `[Rails-controller]` (also `-model`, `-helper`, etc.), but it looks like you would have to manually enable it).

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what it was. It was killing me trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set statusline=%{fnamemodify(bufname('%'),':t')}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick

```
set statusline=%{expand(\"\%\%\")}
```

Comment: actually the [Rails] text still shows up